# UIScrollView in UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am struggling to enable zooming in a `UIPopoverController` using a `UIScrollView`. The scrollView is 600x600 and it should display a view controller that displays a `UIImageView`. The image appears except it's not centered.

This is the code from the `viewDidLoad` method in the view controller that is displayed in the popover.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.imageView.image = self.image;

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:self.imageView.image.size];
    [self.scrollView setDelegate:self];

    [self.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 600)];
    self.view = self.scrollView;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

The `UIScrollView` and `UIImageView` are declared as properties inside the `UIViewController` that's displayed in the popover. `image` is another property that is set to point to an image when the `UIViewController` is created.

This is what is looks like.

[image]

I would like to center the image in the popover and make it fit. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

what you need to do is:

first:

in your uiviewcontroller which is presented as a popover

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)

      preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: collectionPreference.bounds.width, height: collectionPreference.bounds.height)
      println("I am appearing?")
}
```

then from the viewcontroller that is presenting the popover:

make it conform to UIPresentationStyleForPresentingController protocol,

and implement this two things:

number one:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
  return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}
```

number two: in your prepareforsegue method:

```
if let identifier = segue.identifier {
    if identifier == "segueToYourPopoverVC" {
        if let pVC = segue.destinationViewController as? YourPopoverVC {

            let ppc = pVC.popoverPresentationController
            ppc?.delegate = self
        }
     }
}
```

best of luck